# Need to list all names in a column in multiple sheets and the percentage associated with each name

Tags: excel

Sorry for the confusing title, but I don't know how else to phrase it.  I'll just explain.

I have a document with hundreds of entries.  Each sheet is identical, but one sheet per month of information (ie. May, Jun, Jul, etc.)

In each sheet, there's some unrelated information, a Name (ie. joe, Jim, Rob, etc.) and a column with either yes or no.  On a separate sheet, I want to have a list of all unique names that appear, and the percentage of times that Yes appears associated with that name.  I'm not sure what kind of formula will reference multiple sheets for the same info.

Example of the layout of a sheet

```
Joe   Yes
Jim   No
Joe   No
Russ  Yes
Chris No
Russ  Yes
Joe   No
```

If this doesn't make sense, I'll try and clarify.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I can't think of a solution without using VBA. Is the name and Yes/No in the same spot on each sheet?

Comment: same columns, but the orders can change.  There might be many or very few instances of each name in each sheet.

Answer (score 0):

If you can get a list of the names the following will result in the correct percentages:

First create a named range that includes all the sheet names that have the data:

[image]

I called mine `sheets`

Then in the output sheet I listed the unique names in Column A.  In B2 I put this formula:

```
=IF(A2<>"",SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIFS(INDIRECT("'" & sheets & "'!A:A"),A2,INDIRECT("'" & sheets & "'!B:B"),"Yes"))/SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIF(INDIRECT("'" & sheets & "'!A:A"),A2)),"")
```

It will loop through all the sheets looking for the correct data, summing the results as it goes.  It will divide the counts of all that have 'Yes' for the specified name and divide it from the total counts of the name.

[image]

Comment: In this formula, are you assuming B:B refers to the list of names in each sheet, and A:A referring to Yes/No?

When I run this, it gives very odd results which certainly aren't accurate.

Comment: No the columns A have the names and B have the Yes/No. Since you did not define the columns I went with the easiest.

Comment: This is an example of what I've got.  I kept the same name for the named range, have the names of the sheets in column H.

<img src="http://i65.tinypic.com/j7rac1.png">

Comment: They only return stats for the first sheet in the range, nothing else.

Comment: Um, You tagged this excel, but you are using Google sheets.  I am not sure that this works in google sheets. @amace

Comment: Fair Enough.  I'll play around with it, unfortunately it seems to be one of the shortcomings of sheets.

Comment: just did a quick search and Google Sheets does not work with 3D references. @amace